# IntelliJ plugin development - How to find and analyze calls?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, intellij-plugin

I am writing a plugin for IntelliJ IDEA that's main purpose is to help me to use my own API, and now I'm stuck. My API is used the following way:

```java
public class SomeClass {
    @Override
    public void specialMethod() {
        CustomCommand command = CommandManager.registerCommand(CommandClass.class, this);
        command.addMapper("mapper1", ...); // it doesn't matter what is here, the string is the only important thing here
    }
}
```

```java
public class CommandClass extends AbstractCommandClass {
    public CommandClass(SpecialClass specialClass) {
        super(SpecialClass);
    }

    @Mapper("mapper1") // HERE
    public void someMethod() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In annotation `@Mapper` I am using a stringly-typed key and would like my plugin to verify if this string has been registered in `SpecialClass` using `addMapper` method. Additionally, there can be multiple unique mappers, so I also want the suggestion. I know how to create inspections, intentions and providers, the main problem here is: **How to correctly collect all the used strings?**

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [File-Based Indexes](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/file-based-indexes.html).

It works on map-reduce manner. Basically you specify a file-to-keys function and IDEA will build a key-to-file index for you. It will keep the index up to date in case of file changes so you don't need to worry about it. It's even possible to store additional data related to keys.

Then it's possible to query files by key, enumerate all keys or files in the index and so on.